# Mirror skin not working in blender

Tags: rigging

I haven't made skin for a long time (the last time it was around version 3.3).

Now I'm on Blender version 3.5 and then today I installed and 3.61 I cannot get the weight of the bone on one side to be transferred to the other (symmetrical) bone on the other side. Support changed something with the checkboxes?

It's just that the mirror works (when you draw a weight and the weight of the same bone is drawn on the symmetrical side of the mesh), but you need a symmetrical moment. It is strange that such a fundamental thing does not work. This greatly diminishes the value of Blender.

I have been unable to solve this problem for several hours now.

Comment: In the menu on the right of the Vertex Groups list, you can Copy Vertex Group then Mirror Vertex Group? Was there another way to do it?

Comment: Да, я вчера посмотрел много видео. Делал и такое, как Вы предложили - такой способ был предложен в нескольких видео. К сожалению это не моя модель. Мне её дали по работе. У неё весьма слабая оптимизация и она не симметрична. Я вынужден из-за отсутствия решения делать уникальную кожу для каждой из сторон модели. Всё-равно спасибо за ответ. Отсутствие результата тоже результат.

Comment: Hello and welcome. English is mandatory language for the site. If you are not comfortable writing in English feel free to use any online translation service.

Comment: Hello! Excuse me, please. The site translated the text automatically into Russian, even when I wrote in English (instantaneous switching), I thought that this is how it is configured for each location. I tried several times to break through at this point while writing the tag. I will, thank you very much for your comment.